CBOW and Skip-Gram learning perspective
I want to know if I am having a correct understanding of those methods
In CBOW we use nearby words to predict the target word whereas in skip gram we use target word to predict the nearby words,so does that mean that in CBOW we are creating embedding based on what words come often together like "I" will have "am" closely mapped in the dimensional space ,whereas embedding in Skip gram it is more about the meaning of that word like what "am" is used for . Am I correct?
